# Reorder Multiple Line Blocks with Sed

Tags: sed, awk, perl

I am trying to reorder generated output as follows; given a tex fragment as follows, I want to move the `/^Constant/` down below `/Dummies/`, with the line before and after `/^Constant/`.  Further, I would like a stable result, one that does not make a change if `Constant` is already below the last `Dummies` row (it runs as part of a script to fix up my research results, and so far that script is stable).

This is the tex fragment input:

```
[1em]
Application Grade&                  &                  &  -0.0857\sym{***}& -0.00412\sym{***}\\
                &                  &                  & (0.0149)         &(0.00107)         \\
[1em]
Constant        &   -3.701\sym{***}&   -0.311\sym{***}&        0         &        0         \\
                &  (1.130)         & (0.0853)         &      (.)         &      (.)         \\
[1em]
Major Dummies   &       No         &       No         &      Yes         &      Yes         \\
[1em]
Semester Dummies &       No         &       No         &      Yes         &      Yes         \\
\hline
```

This is the desired output, which remains stable (returns the same) if given as input:

```
[1em]
Application Grade&                  &                  &  -0.0857\sym{***}& -0.00412\sym{***}\\
                &                  &                  & (0.0149)         &(0.00107)         \\
[1em]
Major Dummies   &       No         &       No         &      Yes         &      Yes         \\
[1em]
Semester Dummies &       No         &       No         &      Yes         &      Yes         \\
[1em]
Constant        &   -3.701\sym{***}&   -0.311\sym{***}&        0         &        0         \\
                &  (1.130)         & (0.0853)         &      (.)         &      (.)         \\
\hline
```

The following code will do so, but it is not stable.  Basically it matches on `Constant`, drops and re-inserts `[1em]` (which it has to do on a separate call since `i\` affects the output, not the pattern space), and pastes below the target.  It's not stable because it will add bogus `[1em]`s after `Semester Dummies`.  Frankly, its a bit ugly (requiring separate calls to `sed`).

```
sed -E -i'' -e'/^Constant/ {N;h;N;d;}; /^Semester Dummies/ {G;};' fragment.tex
sed -E -i'' -e '/^Semester Dummies/ {a\
\[1em\]
};' fragment.tex
```

I believe a one-liner will do it, matching the multiline pattern `/^\[1em\]\nConstant.*/` (after a call to `N;N;`), putting this in the `h`old buffer, and then pasting it (`G;`) after `/Semester Dummies/`.  But after many hours, man pages, web searches, and upgrading to `gnused` for good measure, I cannot get such a script to work.  This expresses the basic idea but is not valid (s cannot conditionally `h`old as I do here):

```
sed -E -i'' -e'/\[1em\]/ {N;N;s/^\[1em\]\nConstant.*//h;}; /Semester Dummies/ {G;}' fragment.tex
```

I tried many variations relying on `N;P;D;h;G;` with various addressing but I still don't understand the execution order for multiply addressed commands when you are messing with the pattern space (calling `N;`).  `N` and `P` work nicely, but as far as I can tell, `D` is completely useless.

Yes, I know it is easier with `awk` and `perl`; in fact, I would be interested in seeing all three solutions for comparison--but here I am specifically asking how to do it in `sed`.

Answer (score 1):

Here's an ugly piece of awk that plays tricks with the record separator

```
awk -v RS='\\[1em\\]\n|\\\\hline' '
    !/[^[:space:]]/ {next} 
    /^Constant/ {c=$0; next} 
    {printf "[1em]\n%s", $0} 
    END {printf "[1em]\n%s\\hline\n", c}
'
```

Since the text starts and ends with "record separator", there are some spurious empty-ish records, hence the first rule

Comment: This is helpful, though it produces somewhat corrupted output (it seems to replace any backslashes present in the source tex file with '[1em]\n' (a real newline)).  I think awk is probably the right tool for this anyway, so thanks for the hints.

Answer (score 1):

Here is one way to do it with `sed` using the hold buffer:

```
sed '/\[1em\]/{N;/Constant/{N;x;/^$/d;x};/Semester/{x;/^$/!{H;x};//g}}' file
```

On each line matching `[1em]` it reads in the `N`ext line and then

1. If the pattern space matches `Constant` it reads in a`N`other line, e`x`changes the buffers and if the pattern space is just an empty line (that means the hold buffer was empty before exchanging) it is `d`eleted. If the pattern space is not an empty line (which means there was *something* in the hold space because of **2** ) it e`x`changes the buffers again, returning the lines in the pattern space.
2. If the pattern space matches `Semester` it e`x`changes the buffers then, if the patters space isn't empty it means the lines `[1em]\nConstant.*` were in the hold buffer so it appends them to the `[1em]\nSemester.*` lines (which are now in the Hold buffer) and then e`x`changes buffers again. If the pattern space is empty it means the lines `[1em]\nConstant.*` are after the `Semester` line so it just copies the hold space over the pattern space. That way the  `[1em]\nSemester.*` lines are restored but now there is *something* in the hold buffer when it reaches **1**.

This way, the `[1em]\nConstant.*` lines are moved only if they are before `[1em]\nSemester.*`, otherwise nothing happens.

```
sed '/\[1em\]/{             # if line matches [1em]
N                           # read in the next line
/Constant/{                 # if pattern space matches Constant
N                           # read in another line
x                           # exchange buffers
/^$/d                       # if pattern space is now empty, delete it
x                           # otherwise, exchange again
}
/Semester/{                 # if pattern space matches Semester
x                           # exchange buffers
/^$/!{                      # if pattern space is not empty
H                           # append it to hold space
x                           # then exchange buffers
}
//g                         # if pattern space is currently empty
}                           # copy the hold space over the pattern space
}' infile                   # so now the hold space is no longer empty
```

---

This is easier with `ed`. Just select the range of lines and move it after the line matching `Semester`:

```
ed -s infile <<<$'/Constant/-1,/Constant/+1m/Semester/\n,p\nq'
```

replace `,p` with `w` to write changes to file:

```
ed -s infile <<IN
/Constant/-1,/Constant/+1m/Semester/
w
q
IN
```